# Easiest way to capitalize a string within bash 3.2?

Tags: macos, bash, shell

For example: `var=dog` and `echo $var` output is **dog**. *Capitalize `$var`* expected output **Dog**.

Tried multiple ways but just not getting the expected output. *Some attempts:*

```
echo $var | sed "s/[a-z]\&[:upper:]//"  #dog
echo $var | sed "s/([a-z])/[:upper:]/"  #dog
```

Comment: Please clarify if you only want the _very 1st character_ of a given string capitalized or whether you want to capitalize the 1st character of _every word_ (title case).

Comment: @mklement0 just the first word.

Comment: FWIW, it's a Good Idea™ to double-quote Bash parameter expansions unless you _explicitly_ want word splitting and glob expansion to occur. See [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/88378) by Stéphane Chazelas (discoverer (and fixer) of the Shellshock Bash bug). Also, you should generally use `printf` rather than `echo` on arbitrary strings. See Stéphane's answer to [Why is printf better than echo?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/88378).

Comment: After testing all of these solutions, I actually found the python solution by @idjaw best. That said, I +1'd everyone because you all shared great answers. However, I chose to use the python solution because it made the most sense, seemed to be the most flexible, equally fast, easiest to use and implement.

Comment: @Fab: It's great to see your thorough evaluation process and thoughtful feedback. Performance probably won't matter for the occasional invocation, but just for fun I ran tests on my OSX 10.11.1 system: here's the rough timing for 1000 invocations with `'dog'`, fastest first (just to give a sense of _relative_ performance): `tr` and GNU `sed` solutions: ca. 3.2 secs.; GNU `awk` solution; ca. 3.5 secs.; `perl` solution: ca. 6.7 secs.; `python` solution: ca. 20 secs.(!) Conclusion: interpreter startup time matters.

Comment: @Fab: Addendum: Using `echo "${var^}"` in Bash _4+_ (also installable via Homebrew on OS X) is by far the fastest, given the circumstances (a value already stored in a Bash variable): ca. 0.25 secs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Python if that's an option:

After input from different people (thanks all), this seems to be a good working solution  that is in line with OP requests for only the first letter as proposed by @PM2Ring:

*Best proposed solution for first character only*

```
bash-3.2$ var="it's an öyster's life"
bash-3.2$ python -c "import sys;print sys.argv[1].decode('utf8').capitalize()" "$var"
It's an öyster's life
```

Following solutions attempt to capitalize all first characters of words in a string:

*The following solution has some drawbacks:*

```
bash-3.2$ python -c "print raw_input().decode('utf-8').title()" <<<"it's an öyster's life" 
It'S An Öyster'S Life
```

*Simple solution using a variable:*

```
bash-3.2$ var='dog is dog'
bash-3.2$ python -c "print raw_input().decode('utf-8').title()" <<<"$var"
Dog Is Dog
```

As can be seen from the comments in this answer (thanks for the input all), it is important to note the limitations of using this, especially using OSX native Python language 2.7.

Example 1: (Thanks @john1024 & @dev-null)

Quote issues.

small modification with quotes required to handle the below string sample

```
var="it's a dog's life"
bash-3.2$ python -c "print '$var'.title()"
It'S A Dog'S Life
```

Additional example that does not work with my solution:  `var="hello ''' world"`

Example 2: (Thanks @mklement0)

Unicode issues

```
bash-3.2$ var='öyster'
bash-3.2$ python -c "print '$var'.title()"
öYster
```

Notice that it capitalized the second letter, which is the first ascii character that the title method will capitalize per how it is expected in Python2.

The following modification to the solution can be made to help with unicode characters:

```
bash-3.2$ var='öyster'
python -c "print '$var'.decode('utf-8').title()" 
Öyster
```

Finally, when putting the solutions together from the discussion below, this is how it was put together to finally have:

```
python -c "print raw_input().decode('utf-8').title()" <<<"it's an öyster's life"
```

Comment: Good way around OSX limitations (+1) but try with: `var="it's a dog's life"`

Comment: @John1024 Nice catch...you just put me on a mission to try to solve this. Thanks! :P

Comment: Although this shows the limitations of python's title function, consider `echo "$var" | python2 -c "print raw_input().title()"`

Comment: That outputs `It'S A Dog'S Life`. Which is similar to what I got when I ran this modification: `python -c "print '''$var'''.title()"`

Comment: @idjaw and now what happens when `var="hello ''' world"`?

Comment: With Python 3.x this would be Unicode-aware out of the box (and you'd have to use `print` with `()` and `input()` instead of `raw_input()` to make it work); with Python 2.x (OS X 10.11 comes with 2.7.11), it capitalizes the first _ASCII_ character instead; `python -c "print(raw_input().title())" <<<'öyster'` yields `öYster`.

Comment: @dev-null It breaks gloriously. :) Python is probably not the *best* solution for this particular situation. I will note these in my solution if that is OK?

Comment: @mklement0 :) Very good call. I will add these notes to my answer, would be good to note the limitations.

Comment: @mklement0 Solution for unicode in Python2 that I just played around with: `python -c "print '$var'.decode('utf-8').title()"`

Comment: @idjaw: Thanks for updating; if you use `python -c "print raw_input().decode('utf-8').title()" <<<"it's an öyster's life"`, you'll solve _both_ the breaking-with-single-quote and the Unicode issue (though the capitalizing-after-apostrophe issue remains - although it's not even clear whether the OP was looking for _title_ case, as opposed to just capitalizing the very first char. only.)

Comment: That's very true! It was still a fun discussion nonetheless. +1.

Comment: @idjaw: Indeed it was, but I suggest posting the working solution at the top of your answer; those interested in the fun discussion can read on, if they want.

Comment: @mklement0 Very good point. I simply changed to use with the decode call.

Comment: :) thanks; but let's not forget @John1024's contribution: using `raw_input()` combined with stdin input in lieu of a spliced-in shell variable value is what makes input handling truly robust; I think the version in my previous comment does that.

Comment: @mklement0 Ah sorry...I misunderstood which solution you were referring to. Of course!. Corrected. Thanks again.

Comment: As an alternative to the title function, consider: `python -c "print ' '.join(w[0].upper() + w[1:] for w in raw_input().decode('utf-8').split())" <<<"it's an öyster's life"`

Comment: Thanks for your answer and explanation +1, I'll pick a solution tomorrow after further investigation.

Comment: Of course these solutions using `.decode('utf-8')` assume that the console is set to use the `UTF-8` encoding. :) FWIW, here's another Python 2 variant that only capitalizes the first char of the first word of a string in a Bash variable (as per the latest edit on the question); the word is read as a command-line arg. `var="öyster's life"` `python -c "import sys;print sys.argv[1].decode('utf8').capitalize()" "$var"` Output: `Öyster's life`

Comment: I guess I should mention that Bash stores the console's locale in `$LANG` - the encoding is the part after the dot. If there's no dot then the encoding is ASCII. In Python, you can `import locale` and do [locale.getdefaultlocale()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html#locale.getdefaultlocale), which returns a tuple of the form `(language code, encoding)`.

Answer (score 11):

**tl;dr:**

- **macOS, with Unicode support,** ***OR*** **cross-platform, but ASCII-only,** and for **background information**:

  - See the `tr` solution below.
- ***GNU* utilities, with Unicode support** (Linux: preinstalled; macOS: installable via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh)):

  - `sed 's/^./\u&/' <<<'dog' # -> 'Dog'`

    - macOS: after installing with `brew install gnu-sed`, use `gsed` instead of `sed`
  - `awk` alternative: see [dev-null's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33325118/45375)

    - macOS: after installing with `brew install gawk`, use `gawk` instead of `awk`.
- **Cross-platform, with Unicode support**:

  - `perl`: see [dawg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33325793/45375)
  - `python`: see [idjaw's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33325044/45375)
- **Bash 4+, with Unicode support**, which on macOS you can also install with Homebrew:

  - `echo "${var^}"`

---

Try

```
var='dog'
echo "$(tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' <<<"${var:0:1}")${var:1}" # -> 'Dog'
```

- `tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' <<<"${var:0:1}"` extracts the 1st char from `$var` (`${var:0:1}`) and uses `tr` to translate it to uppercase.
- `${var:1}` returns everything from the 2nd char in `$var`'s value.

Note that this solution is **Unicode-aware**<sup>[1]</sup>, unlike the [macOS `awk`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33325118/45375) and [Python 2.x solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33325044/45375) <sup>Update: @idjaw fixed the Python 2.x solution with `.decode('utf-8')`</sup>, and presumably also slightly faster than them (`tr` is lighter-weight than `awk` and `python`).

<sup>[1] This applies to the *BSD* `tr` version that comes with macOS. *GNU* `tr`, by contrast, does *not* handle non-ASCII characters correctly - as [John1024](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3030305/john1024) notes, according to Wikipedia, ["Most versions of tr, including GNU tr and classic Unix tr, operate on single-byte characters and are not Unicode compliant."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_(Unix)).</sup>

---

As for **your attempt at a  `sed` solution**:

Using macOS's (BSD) `sed`, I'm not aware of any *substring*-manipulation features.

If you had ***GNU* `sed`** - which you could install via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) - you could use the following:

```
sed 's/^./\u&/' <<<'dog' # -> 'Dog'
```

`\u` tells GNU Sed to capitalize the following letter. Sadly, you can't do that with macOS's Sed.

`[:upper:]` only ever works as a *matching* character class, it never performs *transformation*, which is why your command didn't work.
The only exception is `tr`, where you can pair an `[:upper:]` with a `[:lower:]` to effect transformation, as in my solution above.

---

Sneak preview of a **Bash *4*+ solution**:

```
var='dog'; echo "${var^}"
```

Comment: Thanks, @John1024; I've added a note to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, @Fab; I've added specific Homebrew hints for `gsed` and also `gawk` to the "tl;dr" section.

Answer (score 4):

```
var="hello world"
echo "$var" | awk '{print toupper(substr($0, 1, 1)) substr($0, 2)}' # Hello world
```

and if you want to Capitalize Each Word:

```
var="hello world"
echo "$var" | awk 'BEGIN{RS = " "};{printf("%s ", toupper(substr($0, 1, 1)) substr($0, 2))}' # Hello World
```

Comment: This works well (except that you should double-quote `$var`), but there's a small caveat (which may not be an issue, depending on your input): OS X's `awk` (BWK Awk) is, sadly, not Unicode-aware; try `echo 'öyster' | awk '{print toupper(substr($0, 1, 1)) substr($0, 2)}'`.

Comment: Thanks; ++ for the clever title-casing solution, but note that it invariably leaves a trailing space after the last newline; a quick fix would be to append `| sed '$d'`

Comment: Thanks for your answer and explanation +1, I'll pick a solution tomorrow after further investigation.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be unicode aware, consider using perl:

```
$ perl -lne 'use open qw(:std :utf8); print ucfirst' <<< 'dog'
Dog
$ perl -lne 'use open qw(:std :utf8); print ucfirst' <<< 'élan'
Élan
```

---

As pointed out in comments:

```
$ perl -C -lne 'print ucfirst' <<< 'élan'
Élan
```

Comment: Nice, but a simpler solution that simply respects whatever the active locale's encoding is is `perl -C -lne 'print ucfirst' <<< 'élan'`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and explanation +1, I'll pick a solution tomorrow after further investigation.